# What to use instead of .container in Gumby2

Tags: css-frameworks, gumby-framework

In [Gumby2](http://gumbyframework.com/), the `container` class is commented with the following comment:

```
// We're removing the container class in favor
// of adding padding to rows at the $device-width
// breakpoint.

/*.container {
    padding: 0 $gutter-in-px;
}*/
```

All I want is to have a central container class that will be in the middle of the screen. I must say I do not understand exactly how to follow this comment. So what is the proposed way for centering such container class in Gumby 2.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `centered` class on your container div (that is a `row`, too).